# How to send images in a jinja html template?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

So I've got a setup of flask + jinja and I'm trying to display an image in an html file being rendered by jinja.

In Python I'm converting it into base64 and then sending it to the template. I'm then using an image tag to display the image.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage }}">
```

I've confirmed that the Python encoding is correct, it displays as it should when I simply write an html file with the base64 embedded into it. Where it seems to fail is from the template modifying the output a little bit. In particular:

```
<img src=3D"data:;base64,/9j/4QAYR
...
baW4WqWj/2Q=3D=3D"/>
```

Jinja seems to be screwing around by adding the text 3D in a couple places where it looks like it shouldn't be. I haven't specified anything differently, and when I printed out myimage just as text, it came up the way I expected it to, starting with /9j and ending with /2Q==

I'm not sure if there's something with the way I'm interpreting it in Jijna or what, but it just doesn't load. I see the image src tag in the email source, but there's just nothing where I expect the image to be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Markup the variable `myimage` as safe:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage | safe }}">
```

Simple single file app (uses requests library):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import base64
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

global _base64_encoded_image


@app.route('/')
def index():
    _html_template = '''
        <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage | safe }}"><p>
        <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage | e }}"><p>    
        <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage }}"><p>
    '''
    global _base64_encoded_image
    return render_template_string(_html_template, myimage=_base64_encoded_image)


@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    global _base64_encoded_image
    _url = "http://via.placeholder.com/200?text=Flask/Jinja2"
    _r = requests.get(_url)
    _base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(_r.content)
    print _base64_encoded_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. It's still coming up as quoted printable as the content-transfer-encoding, and still messing up the encoding with the "3D" that shouldn't be there.

Comment: In template you need to decode byte-object `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myimage.decode('utf-8') | safe }}">`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a URL encoding problem as `=` is a character used in that base64 alphabet and its URL encoding is `%3D`. Try doing a `urllib.quote` on the base64 data before rendering it with Jinja.

Comment: I tried doing urllib.parse.quote before passing off the variable to Jinja but that didn't change the result.

Comment: Can you post the base64 data you're trying to render and what shows up in the rendered HTML? I am testing an example of data with a trailing `==` and have no problems rendering it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I currently cannot post that data. I can just only confirm that when I throw it through a base64 decoder, or write that html in a plain .html file, it renders correctly.